# Phoenix app crashing on Heroku CI

Tags: heroku, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, heroku-ci

We are attempting to port our CI from Travis to Heroku. Tests all pass both locally and on Travis, but on Heroku we are getting some erlang errors that are difficult to debug.

All of the errors seem to arise from tests that make use of the Elixir [Mock](https://github.com/jjh42/mock) module whilst mocking an AWS S3 request.

Here is an example test:

```
  test "put_object failure function" do
    with_mock ExAws, [request!: fn(_) -> %{status_code: 500} end] do
      res = S3.put_object("unique.png", "binary")
      assert res == {:error, "error uploading to S3"}
    end
  end
```

And the put object is simply:

```
  def put_object(unique, image_binary) do
    bucket = System.get_env("BUCKET_NAME")

    res = ExAws.S3.put_object(bucket, unique, image_binary)
    |> ExAws.request!

    case res do
      %{status_code: 200} ->
        {:ok, image_url(unique, bucket)}
      _ ->
        {:error, "error uploading to S3"}
    end
  end
```

So I'm not too sure what is going wrong.

The errors from Heroku CI are here:

```
      8) test put_object failure function (Engine.S3Test)
         test/controllers/s3_test.exs:34
         ** (EXIT from #PID<0.1043.0>) 
{:compile_forms, {:error, [{[], [{:none, :compile, {:crash, :lint_module, {:badarg, [{:erlang, :atom_to_list, [[Application]], []}, 
{:erl_lint, :is_latin1_name, 1, [file: 'erl_lint.erl', line: 3050]}, {:erl_lint, :check_module_name, 3, [file: 'erl_lint.erl', line: 3043]}, 
{:erl_lint, :behaviour_callbacks, 3, [file: 'erl_lint.erl', line: 968]}, {:erl_lint, :all_behaviour_callbacks, 3, [file: 'erl_lint.erl', line: 929]}, 
{:erl_lint, :behaviour_check, 2, [file: 'erl_lint.erl', line: 916]}, {:erl_lint, :post_traversal_check, 2, [file: 'erl_lint.erl', line: 888]}, {:erl_lint, :module, 3, [file: 'erl_lint.erl', line: 534]}, {:compile, :lint_module, 2, [file: 'compile.erl', line: 1109]}, {:compile, :"-internal_comp/5-anonymous-1-", 3, [file: 'compile.erl', line: 342]}, {:compile, :fold_comp, 4, [file: 'compile.erl', line: 369]}, {:compile, :internal_comp, 5, [file: 'compile.erl', line: 353]}, 
{:compile, :"-do_compile/2-anonymous-0-", 2, [file: 'compile.erl', line: 177]}, {:compile, :"-do_compile/2-anonymous-1-", 1, [file: 'compile.erl', line: 190]}]}}}]}], []}}
```

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/jjh42/mock/issues/66. Are you on the latest version of mock/meck?

Comment: That is a great spot! Will look into it now!

Comment: That sorted it. Update mock version to 0.3.1 - `{:mock, "~> 0.3.1", only: :test}`
Thanks @Dogbert

Answer (score 0):

That sorted it thanks to @Dogbert's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905470/phoenix-app-crashing-on-heroku-ci?noredirect=1#comment80757878_46905470)

Update mock version to 0.3.1 - `{:mock, "~> 0.3.1", only: :test}`